# Video plays fine on VLC but stutters on YouTube

Tags: youtube

I have a video that stutters every 3-4 frames on YouTube and was wondering if anyone can give any suggestions on how I can fix it. The video plays fine on the VLC media player.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-9Teinh6Vg&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Does no one have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

This means that one of the following is happening:

- VLC is using hardware acceleration (alias GPU decoding) whereas your browser is not (alias CPU decoding), or vice versa, causing one to bottleneck but not the other.
- VLC is using the AVC codec and your browser VP9. VP9 is much resource intensive than AVC, but does offer a better quality. It also doesn't scale as well over multiple cores.
- VP9 is only hardware-accelerated in modern hardware whereas AVC is quite old by now and hardware-accelerated by everything and their dog.
- your browser is using a higher resolution than VLC, higher resolutions take more power to decode the video.

To fix this, you need to enable/disable hardware acceleration in your browser, use a different browser, or, if neither helps the issue, somehow enhance your processing speed: Closing other programs, cleaning the fans, overclocking the the processors, upgrading the parts – though this is moving beyond the scope of this forum.